# How to update timestamp in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

There is some error when I am executing this php code:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "UPDATE `deposit_admin_report` SET `READING`=$item,`Timestamp`=$today WHERE `METER_NUMBER`='NP-1353-'";
```

Error:

```
 UPDATE `deposit_admin_report` SET `READING`=395,`Timestamp`=2015-11-27 09:08:33 WHERE `METER_NUMBER`='NP-1353-'
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '09:08:33 WHERE `METER_NUMBER`='NP-1353-'' at line 1
```

The column Timestamp has a type "timestamp" and default is "null" in the mysql table.

Will appreciate if anyone could help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: perhaps = '$today' ? accept that its a string not integer and it needs  ' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what you need:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "UPDATE `deposit_admin_report` SET `READING`=$item,`Timestamp`='".$today."' WHERE `METER_NUMBER`='NP-1353-'";
```

Also there is another way:

**Simply use NOW()**

Like this:

$sql = "UPDATE `deposit_admin_report` SET `READING`='$item',`Timestamp`=NOW() 
WHERE `METER_NUMBER`='NP-1353-'";

That's it :)

Comment: Thanks..its really sweet :)

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `NOW()` or change this `$item` to this `'$item'`

```
$sql = "UPDATE `deposit_admin_report` SET `READING`='$item',`Timestamp`=NOW() 
WHERE `METER_NUMBER`='NP-1353-'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "UPDATE `deposit_admin_report` SET `READING`= '" . $item . "',`Timestamp`= '" . $today . "' WHERE `METER_NUMBER`='NP-1353-'";
```

It sees the space in your date as a seperate word, and not as value of your timestamp.

Also, it is way easier to just use `NOW()`

```
$sql = "UPDATE `deposit_admin_report` SET `READING`= '" . $item . "',`Timestamp`= 'NOW()' WHERE `METER_NUMBER`='NP-1353-'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Date field accepts a string which you should enclose in single quotes.

```
  $sql = "UPDATE `deposit_admin_report` SET `READING`= $item, `Timestamp`= '$today' WHERE `METER_NUMBER`='NP-1353-'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered. Would like to bring into notice the caveat of using `NOW()` in `Master / Slave` architecture.

If timezone of slave server is different than that of master, the timestamp value stored on master will be different than the one on slave.

Its recommended to use following steps:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // UTC is an example

$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "
UPDATE `deposit_admin_report`
SET `READING`=$item,`Timestamp`='".$today."'
WHERE `METER_NUMBER`='NP-1353-'
";
```